# How can I express the fact that the reason why I wore pants has been the same?

Tags: meaning, phrase-requests, time

Since the start of the latest lockdowns, I haven't been wearing pants often. The only times when I wear it have been when I meet with a particular friend of mine. Now, I want to express the fact that this particular friend of mine has been the only reason why I wore pants. However, I'm having a bit of trouble:

If I say

> S/he has been the only reason I have been wearing since the start of the latest lockdown.

The reader might understand as if I have been wearing pants for several months now. Even though the act of *wearing pants* has been done several times for short time periods, the reason why such an act has been the same. So, when I say "since ...", the time phrase should modify the noun *reason* and not *wear*.

How can I express what I want to say, just like in the above example, in a single sentence without causing possible confusion?

Comment: Since the latest lockdown, she’s the only reason I’ve worn pants.

Comment: But @Jim, since "Since the latest lockdown" refers to the verb "to be", shouldn't it be in present perfect tense? By its nature, *since* refers to a time frame started in the past and still continuing.

Comment: First of all, make sure you are not in the U.K. or that she is not a Brit:  if she is, she will wonder why you are not at other times wearing any underpants (or, presumably, what we Brits call 'trousers').  'pants' is the word in British English for what Americans call 'underpants' or sometimes 'shorts'.

Comment: What @Jim said is fine. Few people will assume that you've been wearing the same pair of pants for one year and three months, or however long this attempt to flatten the curve has been going on.